# Angular2 SVG xlink:href

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have component for rendering SVG icon:

```ts
import {Component, Directive} from 'angular2/core';
import {COMMON_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
  selector: '[icon]',
  directives: [COMMON_DIRECTIVES],
  template: `<svg role="img" class="o-icon o-icon--large">
                <use [xlink:href]="iconHref"></use>
              </svg>{{ innerText }}`
})
export class Icon {
  iconHref: string = 'icons/icons.svg#menu-dashboard';
  innerText: string = 'Dashboard';
}
```

This triggers error:

```ts
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
  Can't bind to 'xlink:href' since it isn't a known native property ("<svg role="img" class="o-icon o-icon--large">
<use [ERROR ->][xlink:href]=iconHref></use>
  </svg>{{ innerText }}"): SvgIcon@1:21
```

How do I set dynamic `xlink:href`?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

SVG elements doen't have properties, therefore attribute binding is required most of the time (see also [Properties and Attributes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003819/properties-and-attributes-in-html)).

For attribute binding you need

```ts
<use [attr.xlink:href]="iconHref">
```

or

```ts
<use attr.xlink:href="{{iconHref}}">
```

**Update**

Sanitization might cause issues.

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9510)
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/DomSanitizationService-class.html

**Update** `DomSanitizationService` is going to be renamed to `DomSanitizer` in RC.6

**Update** this should be fixed

but there is an open issue to support this for namespaced attributes https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/6363/files

As work-around add an additional

```ts
xlink:href=""
```

Angular can update the attribute but has issues with adding.

If `xlink:href` is actually a property then your syntax should work after the PR was added as well.

Comment: Thanks! Now the iconHref is rendered in DOM.. Still the icon is not displayed just as I the SVG did not pick the change. Seems like the PR is needed for this to work.

Comment: Note this also works for an image tag. `<image attr.xlink:href="http://somewhere.com/{{restOfUrl}}" />`

Answer (score 3):

I was still having issues with the attr.xlink:href described by [Gunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217408/g%c3%bcnter-z%c3%b6chbauer) so I created a directive that is similar to [SVG 4 Everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody) but is specific for angular2.

### Usage

`<div [useLoader]="'icons/icons.svg#menu-dashboard'"></div>`

### Explanation

This directive will

1. Load icons/icons.svg over http
2. Parse the response and extract path info for #menu-dashboard
3. Add the parsed svg icon to the html

### Code

```
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

// Extract necessary symbol information
// Return text of specified svg
const extractSymbol = (svg, name) => {
    return svg.split('<symbol')
    .filter((def: string) => def.includes(name))
    .map((def) => def.split('</symbol>')[0])
    .map((def) => '<svg ' + def + '</svg>')
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[useLoader]'
})
export class UseLoaderDirective implements OnChanges {

    @Input() useLoader: string;

    constructor (
        private element: ElementRef,
        private http: Http
    ) {}

    ngOnChanges (values) {
        if (
            values.useLoader.currentValue &&
            values.useLoader.currentValue.includes('#')
        ) {
            // The resource url of the svg
            const src  = values.useLoader.currentValue.split('#')[0];
            // The id of the symbol definition
            const name = values.useLoader.currentValue.split('#')[1];

            // Load the src
            // Extract interested svg
            // Add svg to the element
            this.http.get(src)
            .map(res => res.text())
            .map(svg => extractSymbol(svg, name))
            .toPromise()
            .then(svg => this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = svg)
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be solved using angular pipe feature.

```
<use attr.xlink:href={{weatherData.currently.icon|iconpipe}}></use>
```

**Explanation**
This pipe will

1. Pass the parsed response value to the pipe
2. Return the complete svg path
3. `attr.xlink:href=` will get the expected path & svg will rendered in
   html page

here is pipe typescript code

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'iconpipe'
})
export class IconPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor() { }

    transform(value: any) {
        let properIconName = undefined;

        switch (value) {
            case 'clear-day':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#sun';
                break;
            case 'clear-night':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#night-1';
                break;
            case 'partly-cloudy-day':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#cloudy';
                break;

            case 'partly-cloudy-night':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#night';
                break;

            case 'cloudy':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#cloud';
                break;

            case 'rain':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#rain';
                break;

            case 'sleet':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#snowflake';
                break;
            case 'snow':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#snowing';
                break;

            case 'wind':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#storm';
                break;
            case 'fog':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#sun';
                break;
            case 'humid':
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#sun';
                break;
            default:
                properIconName = '/assets/images/weather-SVG-sprite.svg#summer';
        }
        return properIconName;
    }
}
```