# xlink:href is not working in angular2 d3js

Tags: angular, d3.js

```
let img = g.append('svg:image')
        .attr('xlink:href',this.image_url)
        .attr('width',576)
        .attr('height',432)
        .attr('x',0)
        .attr('y',0);
```

The above code is to get the image from the specified url, but i could not load the image.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker? Are you using `<base href="/">` with a different value than `/`?

Comment: I am using the base href = "/".

Comment: You have to sanitize svg img.

Comment: @micronyks, can you please provide me some references?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082657/angular2-svg-xlinkhref