# (error) binding does not working on <image> tag within <svg> in IE11/Angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a web app which attempts to load an image inside an svg. If the image can't load, it uses an (error) binding to replace the image with something else. Although this works fine in Chrome, the (error) binding does not fire in IE11.

I have installed classlist.js and included it in polyfills.ts, but it has had no effect on the binding.

My code:

```html
<svg>
    <image [attr.xlink:href]="src" (error)="console.log('uh oh')"></image>
</svg>
```

I expect to see "uh oh" in the console when I set `this.src="/notarealimage.png"`. Although this works in Chrome, it does not work in IE11. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: Hello, "console.log('uh oh')" seems better than closing your double quote, not sure it's the reason why it does not work but try it. My other recommandation is to use <img [src] as I don't know <image
Can you tell me what's your angular version ?

Comment: hello you can find the solution in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082657/angular2-svg-xlinkhref

Comment: @andrea06590 That was a mistake on my part when typing up my issue here - the original code did it properly

Comment: @YeissonJimenez That seems to be an unrelated issue. Also, it wouldn't explain why it works in Chrome and not IE